# Tag more en wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Estoy intentando utilizar el tag more en wordpress pero no hace nada, os dejo capturas a continuacion.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y asi se ve, no aparece el "leer mas"
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: quiza debes meter el codigo en la pestaña llamada HTML y no en la pestaña VISUAL (según veo en la captura)

Comment: @Dr.Manhattan He buscado en foro y se ve que la opcion de read more solo es aplicable a entradas, en page no se puede utilizar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El tag more solo funciona en post y entrada. En paginas no funciona!